# svg in ios4 - image pattern

Tags: ios4, svg

I'm generating an SVG file, which should be viewed on iPhones. As iOS4 doesn't support the <SVG> tag properly, I encode the whole SVG code to base64, and use it as a data URI for an <IMG> tag.

In most cases, this works properly.

However, in one of the SVGs I have an image pattern:

```
<pattern id="noise" height="20" width="135"  patternTransform="translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1) rotate(0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image x="0" y="0" opacity="1" height="20" width="135" xlink:href=(image uri) />
</pattern>
```

When the SVG code containing it is converted and shown as an image on iOS4, the image is treated as if it has a broken link. On iOS5, though, it works properly.

Why does this happen? How do I correct this?